# R - How can I add from an XML-File for a number of childnodes the corresponding node?

Tags: r, xml

I have an XML-File with a huge number of Nodes. Each Sub-Sub-Node(//item/sizes/size) should get the corresponding sub-node(//item/number). Here is an example of the code:

```
<item>
    <itemtype>A</itemtype>
    <number>200379084</number>
    <supplier>
        <id>1091</id>
        <name>Brand 1</name>
    </supplier>
    <sizes>
        <size>
            <sizeid>2</sizeid>
            <sizebarcode>116</sizebarcode>
            <sizeshort>116</sizeshort>
            <sizelong>    116</sizelong>
            <UmgerechneteGG/>
            <ean>643345344363628</ean>
            <stock>0</stock>
            <stockperstore/>
        </size>
        <size>
            <sizeid>3</sizeid>
            <sizebarcode>128</sizebarcode>
            <sizeshort>128</sizeshort>
            <sizelong>    128</sizelong>
            <UmgerechneteGG/>
            <ean>64334534543363635</ean>
            <stock>0</stock>
            <stockperstore/>
        </size>
        <size>
            <sizeid>4</sizeid>
            <sizebarcode>140</sizebarcode>
            <sizeshort>140</sizeshort>
            <sizelong>    140</sizelong>
            <UmgerechneteGG/>
            <ean>64334534563642</ean>
            <stock>0</stock>
            <stockperstore/>
        </size>
        <size>
            <sizeid>5</sizeid>
            <sizebarcode>152</sizebarcode>
            <sizeshort>152</sizeshort>
            <sizelong>    152</sizelong>
            <UmgerechneteGG/>
            <ean>6438345359</ean>
            <stock>0</stock>
            <stockperstore/>
        </size>
        <size>
            <sizeid>6</sizeid>
            <sizebarcode>164</sizebarcode>
            <sizeshort>164</sizeshort>
            <sizelong>    164</sizelong>
            <UmgerechneteGG/>
            <ean>64334553666</ean>
            <stock>0</stock>
            <stockperstore/>
        </size>
        <size>
            <sizeid>7</sizeid>
            <sizebarcode>176</sizebarcode>
            <sizeshort>176</sizeshort>
            <sizelong>    176</sizelong>
            <UmgerechneteGG/>
            <ean>643834553473</ean>
            <stock>0</stock>
            <stockperstore/>
        </size>
    </sizes>
</item>
<item>
    <itemtype>A</itemtype>
    <number>200379086</number>
    <supplier>
        <id>4140</id>
        <name>Brand 2</name>
    <sizes>
        <size>
            <sizeid>2</sizeid>
            <sizebarcode>116</sizebarcode>
            <sizeshort>116</sizeshort>
            <sizelong>    116</sizelong>
            <UmgerechneteGG/>
            <ean>57234342233804</ean>
            <stock>0</stock>
            <stockperstore/>
        </size>
        <size>
            <sizeid>3</sizeid>
            <sizebarcode>128</sizebarcode>
            <sizeshort>128</sizeshort>
            <sizelong>    128</sizelong>
            <UmgerechneteGG/>
            <ean>5713434323811</ean>
            <stock>0</stock>
            <stockperstore/>
        </size>
        <size>
            <sizeid>4</sizeid>
            <sizebarcode>140</sizebarcode>
            <sizeshort>140</sizeshort>
            <sizelong>    140</sizelong>
            <UmgerechneteGG/>
            <ean>5723432128</ean>
            <stock>0</stock>
            <stockperstore/>
        </size>
        <size>
            <sizeid>5</sizeid>
            <sizebarcode>152</sizebarcode>
            <sizeshort>152</sizeshort>
            <sizelong>    152</sizelong>
            <UmgerechneteGG/>
            <ean>513434323835</ean>
            <stock>0</stock>
            <stockperstore/>
        </size>
        <size>
            <sizeid>6</sizeid>
            <sizebarcode>164</sizebarcode>
            <sizeshort>164</sizeshort>
            <sizelong>    164</sizelong>
            <UmgerechneteGG/>
            <ean>5723423423242</ean>
            <stock>0</stock>
            <stockperstore/>
        </size>
        <size>
            <sizeid>7</sizeid>
            <sizebarcode>176</sizebarcode>
            <sizeshort>176</sizeshort>
            <sizelong>    176</sizelong>
            <UmgerechneteGG/>
            <ean>572342323459</ean>
            <stock>0</stock>
            <stockperstore/>
        </size>
    </sizes>
</item>
</products>
```

Add the End, I would like to get in RStudio an DataFrame with the Columns "sizeshort", "ean","stock" (//item/sizes/size) and number (//item/number).

For example:

```
ID  EAN            Stock  Number  
7   572342323459   0      200379086  
6   5723423423242  0      200379086  
5   513434323835   0      200379086
```

Thank you so much for your help.